# pgAdmin 4 does not show result after query execution (postgreSQL)

Tags: sql, postgresql, file, pgadmin-4

I have a big SQL file which have some queries. I wish to know how many time takes the execution of the entire file.

I open the file in "Query Tool" in pgAdmin 4 and it takes 1 minute to execute "successfully" but when I go to "View data", the table is empty (this must not happen because the file has 100.000 insertions, some selections and it does not have any deletion).

It is not a system error because I execute another query an it works. The SQL file size is 32,4 MB.

Why does this happen?

Could be due to the file size?

Comment: What happens when you break the file up?

Comment: Is the last statement in the file *not* a `SELECT` statement?

Comment: I found that in pgAdmin 3, it takes 3 hours, 34 mins and 48 seconds to execute. I broke up the file in two parts, the insertion section and the selection/update section; in this moment the insertion section works but I have not tested the second section pgAdmin 4. May be pgAdmin 4 does not support big files, I think that pgAdmin 3 is better than pgAdmin 4 in this case.

Comment: You are saying "big" and then saying 32.4 Mb. Is there a typo there? 32.4 Mb is not big (well it is a relative term), neither is 100 K insertions. (Personally I like pgAdmin 3 LTS by Bigsql). 3 hrs for 32.4 Mb is unacceptable IMHO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing to consider is the status of autocommit. Remember that in some circumstances you can issue a lot of insert statements, but none of them will take effect unless they are committed. The query may not be seeing anything because the transactions have not been made permanent by the time the select is issued.

Comment: Thank you, you help me a lot. In fact, when I go to "View Data" and it is empty it is because PgAdmin did not commit the changes, it is because the selection takes much more time than the insertions due the nature of the queries. When I run only the insertions it takes 3.4 seconds approximately.